# Delphi XE2 Firemonkey iOS app controls compatibility

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

As you all know, Embarcadero just released Delphi XE2. I have download it and i am very excited about having an way of creating an iOS app.

To create the iOS app we should export the code to xcode. But the question is: does every control works on iOS/xcode? I mean, if i want to connect to a sql lite database can I use the delphi controls to do so?

Is there any way of accessing some specific things in iOS like acelerometer and camera?

Is it possible to create a useful iPhone/Ipad app in Delphi (connect to a database, load grids, connect to a webservice, for example)?

Comment: I understand your excitement but I think you need to ask one question at a time.

Comment: My questions are all related to the same subject. The firemonkey/xcode compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- I don't think you can [Components Not Used in iOS Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Components_Not_Used_in_iOS_Apps)

-- I think you can use the TDatasource and the TClientDataSet though ;-)

2- Delphi uses FPC compiler for the iOS so you'll have to parse the iOS SDK headers before you can use it [Parsing iOS headers](http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP/Xcode4/ObjP_Part3.html#ParsingHeaders) or http://wiki.freepascal.org/objectivepascal#iOS_Headers but there are no out-of-the-box components (yet) that can access the Camera, Accelerometer, ...

3- Check number 1.

Answer (score 1):

Actually ... I think TClientDataSet isn't supported on iOS. I could be wrong ... but at least it wasn't supported a few months ago.